# Anonymous functions does not work: Function name must be a string

Tags: php

I have:

```
PHP Version 5.4.20
'./configure' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

And I test this code:

```
$greet = function($name) {
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('PHP');
```

I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string
```

On PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 it is working as it should. Does anyone what is going on?

Comment: [Cannot confirm?](http://3v4l.org/AM45b)

Comment: This may have no bearing on the questions, but which version of PHP is it really?  In the first part of your post, you say 5.4.20.  In the last sentence, you say 5.3.10.

Comment: Works on `PHP 5.5.5 (cli)`

Comment: @h2ooooooo My mistake.  I missed that part.

Comment: What does `var_dump(phpversion());` output?

Comment: ..and what does `var_dump($greet)` output?

Comment: Do you install php from the source code or using the package manager as YUM or apt-get

Comment: Are you sure you're not doing `function $greet($name){}` or `$greet = [function($name){}];`?  The code you posted here works.  Are you sure your code is the correct syntax?

Comment: It is not working on 5.4.20. I hot version number via phpinfo(). I tried with php_version() and it is 5.4.20.

Comment: And yes, I am quite sure syntax is ok. It is copy/paste example from http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php . I wanted to be sure that problem is with anonymous functions. And I am still trying to figure out where the problem is

Answer (score 5):

Uhh, I think I just find out  :( : http://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/eaccelerator-and-php-closures-dont-mix

Answer (score 1):

its because of **eAccelerator**  and you should disable it

To turn off eAccelerator, make the following changes in your **php.ini** configuration:

```
eaccelerator.enable 0
eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

or in  ***.htaccess*** files

```
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw, I noticed problem with this server (it is client's VPN server) when I uploaded symfony application and I got this error

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, '', to be a valid callback in /home/client/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Unescaper.php line 56
```